# PHP Application reporting empty data to New Relic

Tags: php, newrelic

I recently started using New Relic and I think I have everything set up correctly. When I run `php -i`, it shows up as a command line transaction. However, when I try to run my worker process (I've tried it with both `php -f worker.php` and `./worker.php` where the shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/php`) the app shows up in New Relic, but no transactions or any data whatsoever appear. Is there something I need to add to my code or am I starting it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The New Relic PHP agent is designed to monitor your web applications so that is the default setup.  Have you checked your dashboard to see if there is data in the "Other" category?  Click on the "Request response time" to find it. This is where CLI requests would normaly appear. If this does not assist you it will probably require that New Relic support assist you by looking at your specific account/application.  Open a support ticket with them.

Comment: When I ran `php -i` it made an application called "PHP Application". There is data in the other category here, but the only transaction is `php -i`. The app with the name I set has no data under other.